# Expedia API integration

Tags: php

I have a web application of travel portal in core php. I want to integrate Expedia API in this portal. I have successfully integrate Expedia API but when end user search the flights, Hotels and Cars the next is displaying exampletravel.com. I have changed every URL in source file. Can any one help me how to stop redirecting on example travel.com,

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code please? It's near impossible to help in most cases otherwise.

Comment: I have multiple files of code for Expedia integration...

Comment: i can share URL of  page   http://skelbimuturgus.lt/postAds.php?filename=travel.php&IId=59